# Single word for "64-bit signed integer"

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

Are there any single words that name concepts like "very large integer"?  I would prefer a single word that could describe any integer from minus nine quintillion through nine quintillion.  (Computers use 64-bit signed integers to represent these things.)

I wish to use this word in sentences like this:

> Pick a _____________.
>   Pick another _____________.
>   Multiply the _____________ by the other _____________.
>   Subtract the _____________'s square root from the other _____________.

**Similar words that don't quite fit:**

Unfortunately, I cannot just use the words `number` or `long` for this purpose, because they already have well-understood meanings -- both in English in general, and in my particular context.

In English, there are single words for particular very large integers, such as trillion and quadrillion.

In computer programming, there are words for modest or large integers:

- a `char` or `byte` is usually in the range 0 through 255.
- an `int` is sometimes in the range from -32,768 through 32,768.
- a `word` (or sometimes a `uint`) is usually in the range from 0 through 65,535.
- an `long` (or sometimes an `int`) is usually in the range from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.
- a `dword` or a `ulong` (or sometimes a `uint`) is usually in the range from 0 through 4,294,967,295.

**Searches I have performed:**

I performed DuckDuckGo searches for "word for a very large integer", "words for different sizes of number", and similar search terms (all without the quotes).  I found [pages](http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/words/intro.htm) explaining how to build words for particular very large integers (such as "trillion"), and mentioning words that are about vague (but implicitly particular) very large integers such as "zillion" or "gazillion".  I also found thesaurus pages with adjectives meaning "very large", but that were not combined into a single word with any affix meaning number.

Comment: Just as point of note, the range you specify in the first paragraph contains integers like 0 and 1.

Comment: "I would prefer a single word that could describe any integer from minus nine quintillion through nine quintillion."  That would include 1,2,3 and other small numbers.  Also unclear why you want to stop at nine quintillion, which is actually not that large a number.   Can you clarify why you want this word?

Comment: My rule, and I frequently obey it to the exasperation of many, is that if I cannot find what I want in English, I invent something of my own. I suggest a 'nonaquinteger'.

Comment: [`bigint`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)? Or maybe [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)?

Comment: @Jim -- Yes, I am aware that small integers are in the range.  I would be happy with either a word that is meant to describe just very large integers (but not small or medium integers), or a word that inclusively describes the entire range.

Comment: You'd say "very large integer".  If you need to be more specific then "integer between -9,000,000,000,000,000,000 and 9,000,000,000,000,000,000, inclusive."

Comment: The Microsoft Windows API defines a "[hyper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230331.aspx)" as a 64-bit integer (__int64).  A "hyper" can be either signed or unsigned.  Yes, this is an answer in a comment.  The question needs to be re-opened to put this answer in an actual answer.

Comment: Given your audience, a technical term like int64 is appropriate. Why invent a word when there's a known reference that identifies what you want, maps to the computer's architecture, and is referenced in other sources for decades?

Comment: @jimm101 -- The audience for this insists on using plain english.  Except for specific numbers like 12345, none of the other words in the text need to be written using digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL (e.g. [T-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)), a **`bigint`** has a range of:

> -2<sup>63</sup> (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

In other words, a [**64 bit signed integer**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003492/6083675).